# Common django templates parameter

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 10 django routes which render 10 templates. Those 10 templates uses the same layout (extends). I want to send the same Context parameters for those 10 routes. Is there a way, in view.py, to set those parameters without duplicating code ?
Thanks

Comment: Yes: [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects).

Comment: Yes i know this but do you think i should create a common function in view.py which will create this context object and then call this function in last parameter of render() ?

Comment: Er, what? Context processors are the solution already and are automatically called for you. Why do you want to call anything manually?

Comment: Context processors are fine, but they are invoked for each and any use of a `TemplateContext`. I once had to fix a project where someone used and abused context processors to the point we had huge performance issues on production, and that was not quite a party :-/ - so while it _may_ be the right solutions for things that are not computationnaly heavy and are really of general use throughout the whole project, I'd rather not use them as a goto solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "simplest solution that could possibly work":

```
def render_common(request, template):
    context = {
        # set up you context here
        }
    return render(request, template, context)


def viewone(request):
    return render_common(request, "templateone.html")

# etc
```

Or if you have additional per-view specific context:

```
def render_common(request, template, extra_context):
    context = {
        # set up you context here
        }
    context.update(extra_context) 
    return render(request, template, context)


def viewone(request):
    return render_common(request, "templateone.html", {"foo":"bar"})
```

Another solution - depending on your concrete use case - might be to write a set of custom templatetags.